# Gatling logs in Json

Tags: json, kibana, gatling

usually Gatling's stdout looks like this:

```
================================================================================
2018-10-14 22:37:13                                        3035s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=5894925 KO=0     )
> Api1                                                     (OK=3177389 KO=0     )
> Api2                                                     (OK=2717536 KO=0     )

---- Api1 ----------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 30     / done:0
---- Api2 ---------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 30     / done:0
================================================================================
```

Is there any way to transform this output into some sort of json output? I need so it can be automatically ingested by a RELK stack (redis, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your `/target/gatling/<simulation>` folder should have a `simulation.log` file which is a TSV. You could easily injest and convert this to JSON.